# Search an element from the form element using css

Tags: html, css, forms, input

To make a search tab I have executed the following:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>
```

However if I want to search another element from the same html page like say a paragraph named "123"  using this search tab how can I proceed?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please put a snippet.

Comment: You are asking if how to search another element either with an `ID`, a `name` or a `class` using an `input`, right?

Comment: Yeah to search any element using the input element

Comment: I believe you need to use JavaScript for this task: `document.querySelector('input[name=search]').addEventListener('input', function(event) { console.log(document.getElementById(event.target.value)) })`

Comment: Can you tell me where to add this java command in the html script, like after the form tag or the input tag or so on? @wostex

Comment: @anonymous this is too broad question, you should learn a whole programming language in order to to that. You'd better find a javascript programmer and give him a precise task. And remember, javascript in not java, these things are totally different.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help. Will surely look forward to learning what all of these terms are. @wostex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty simple please give a 5 rating to this answer !!!

```css
input[type=text]
{
background-color:green;
font-size:40px;
}
input[type=email]
{
background-color:red;
font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<form>

<input type=text placeholder="i an text and i am green"><br>
<input type=email placeholder="i an email and i am red"><br>


</form>
```